# Accessibility issue with large letters on Android

Tags: android, react-native

Is there a way when the React Native app opens on Android it makes the android letters go out of accessibility mode and back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

To turn font scaling off completely:

```
allowFontScaling={false}
```

To limit font scaling, use:

```
maxFontSizeMultiplier={multiplierValue}
```

If you only want to do this on Android:

```
allowFontScaling={Platform.OS === 'android' && false}
```

This prop works on Text and TextInput components.

Comment: Thank u. I'm gonna try